# VS python import function Error - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, modulenotfounderror

In VS, I wrote a very simple function, which I saved and then wanted to import in another file, but I get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

I think it is because the paths doesn't line up. but I have no idea to what I have to change it. Other answers to similar questions didn't work / I didn't understand.

I also don't have an `__init__` file next to it, which I don't know if have to do manually?

File with function named "pizza.ipynb":

```
def make_pizza(size, *toppings):
    """Summarize the pizza we are about to make."""
    print(f"\nMaking a {size}-inch pizza with the following toppings:")
    for topping in toppings:
        print(f"- {topping}")
```

2nd file:

```
import pizza

pizza.make_pizza(16, 'pepperoni')
pizza.make_pizza(12, 'mushrooms', 'green peppers', 'extra cheese')
```

Comment: Could you please add your directory structure to the problem, which will help us solve it for you.